# How to make a function that plots given functions on a specific range

Tags: r

I an trying to make a function which has a few special arguments.

This function should have the arguments (f1, f2 and range). The range would be the interval for the function f1 and f2. The function could be f1=cosx and f2=2x. Then the function should plot the two functions on that range on one single plot.

This is the example I have right now in my mind and an outline for the function:

```
f1=cosx 
f2=2x
range=

MasterFun<- function(f1,f2,range) {

range <- interval for the function to be calculte
curve (the functions on the same plot)

      }
```

I do not know how to make MasterFun. How do I do this? I am cunfused how to make the inner functions just use the numbers in the "range" argument.

2) And going a bit more complicated:  what if the function has more variables for input? For example if I use a function like this

```
 2^(2*k+n)
```

how can I make the range for mutiple variables for that function?

3) How can I calulate for example 50 points equally separated for each function ?

4) What if I give the range inside the function? How should the function look like then?

I would like to do this only with basic R graphics.

Comment: I recommend reading some documentation first. Range, for instance, could be a list of length 2, try ?list. As to plotting functions in a given range using sample points (item #3), try ?seq. For passing multidimensional range, you could use a list again, or a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for commeting. I tried to find something about this and but I still confused about it. Do you have any documentation with examples for this?

Comment: So you want to write a wrapper function for two calls to `curve`? Why not simply call it twice? This way you'll also free youself from including `xlim, ylim,...` and what you might need into the definition of the wrapper function. I find this hardly worth the effort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first capture the ... arguments in `dots`, form the `x` values to evaluate the function at and then calculate y limits, `ylim`, wide enough to include all functions.  Finally run curve.  We do this inside an `eval/substitute` to get around the non-standard evaluation that `curve` uses.

```
Master <- function(..., Range = 0:1, n = 101, ylab = "", xname = "x", 
     env = parent.frame()) {
  dots <- substitute(...())
  x <- seq(Range[1], Range[2], length = n)

  rng <- function(e) {
    expr <- if (is.name(e)) {
        call(as.character(e), as.name(xname))
    } else {
        if (!((is.call(e) || is.expression(e)) && xname %in% 
            all.vars(e))) 
            stop(
             gettextf("'expr' must be a fun, or a call or an expr containing '%s'", 
              xname), domain = NA)
        e
    }
    ll <- list(x = x)
    names(ll) <- xname
    y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = env)
    range(y)
  }
  ylim <- range(c(sapply(dots, rng)))

  for(i in seq_along(dots)) {
    if (i > 1) par(new = TRUE)
    eval(substitute(do.call(curve, list(dots[[i]], 
       from = Range[1], to = Range[2], n = n, 
       ylim = ylim, ylab = ylab))), env)
  }

k <- 1}
Master(cos, 2*x, x+n+k)
```

which gives:

[image: screenshot]

**Improvements added**

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you show me how would the function look like with
`plot ()`

I think it would look shorter and you did not need to eval and
substitute.

Comment: Over half the function (the `rng` function and the `ylim<-` line) compute `ylim` so if you passed that to the function rather than compute it that would cut it down by quite a bit.

Comment: As I can see, you have a very high reputation. How did you learn R?
I know its a stupid question, but I want to be as good as possible I can be, but I am not sure how to exercise my skill. Do you have any advice? Daily exercise?